# Logging in console application (.NET Core with DI)

Tags: c#, logging, dependency-injection, console-application

guys. I try to add logging to my console app with DI (.NET Core 3.1) and seems that IoC container works fine for that, injects logger dependency to my classes, but LogXXX method doesn't log to output. What can be the reason? Maybe there are some additional configurations?

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace DependencyInjection
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var services = new ServiceCollection();
            ConfigureServices(services);

            var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

            var logger = serviceProvider.GetService<ILogger<Program>>();
            logger.LogInformation("Hello world!");
        }

        static void ConfigureServices(ServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddLogging(loggerBuilder =>
            {
                loggerBuilder.ClearProviders();
                loggerBuilder.AddConsole();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#add-providers and read the part about non hosted console app. you have to create the factory yourself

Comment: Actually, I've found that disposing serviceProvicer at the end of  Main() solves the problem. Just added serviceProvider.Dispose();

Answer (score 44):

[Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#non-host-console-app) have current example for Console App

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
        {
            builder
                .AddFilter("Microsoft", LogLevel.Warning)
                .AddFilter("System", LogLevel.Warning)
                .AddFilter("LoggingConsoleApp.Program", LogLevel.Debug)
                .AddConsole();
        });
        ILogger logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Program>();
        logger.LogInformation("Example log message");
    }
}
```

Of course you need to install the appropriate Nuget packages:

- `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`
- `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console`

Comment: How can I access the logger from another class? Is there a way to make it available by DI?

Comment: Using serviceProvider from your original question, use 
var logger = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>())

Comment: I'm not sure why they took this out of the documentation for newer versions! All the new docs show using a web app builder.

Comment: @Lamar just use the example from the question. Also check my answer for some explanations.

Answer (score 0):

> What can be the reason? Maybe there are some additional configurations?

As of at least [.net-6.0](/questions/tagged/.net-6.0) `ConsoleLogger` is actually asynchronous and utilizes currently internal [`ConsoleLoggerProcessor`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/8383c97e937f4de36658aafc665b92cb88dc9aa8/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console/src/ConsoleLoggerProcessor.cs#L15) (in some previous versions seems that [it was public](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/pull/477/files#diff-afefab5061b05757f82144118046b74eaa08cb3ae9964c341456b80aa8d964f9)) which [utilizes a separate thread](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/8383c97e937f4de36658aafc665b92cb88dc9aa8/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console/src/ConsoleLoggerProcessor.cs#L71) to process the messages and write them to console which can result in some unexpected behaviors (like missed messages on app exit or for example if you hit a breakpoint in simple console app). `ConsoleLoggerProcessor` [implements `IDisposable`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/8383c97e937f4de36658aafc665b92cb88dc9aa8/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console/src/ConsoleLoggerProcessor.cs#L185) currently looking like the following:

```
public void Dispose()
{
    CompleteAdding();

    try
    {
        _outputThread.Join(1500); // with timeout in-case Console is locked by user input
    }
    catch (ThreadStateException) { }
}
```

So one workaround would be to dispose the service provider which will dispose the instantiated by it disposables (for debugging in some cases I've used some timeouts and steps throughs to "get" the message in the console):

```
var services = new ServiceCollection();
// optional if you want to read the config.
var cfg = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
    .Build();
services.AddSingleton(cfg);

services.AddLogging(lb => lb.AddSimpleConsole());

// Dispose service provider
using var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
var requiredService = sp.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
requiredService.LogError("Test");
```

Note that all of this is handled by hosting abstractions (like [generic host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/generic-host) nowadays used by worker templates or minimal hosting used for ASP.NET Core by default since .NET 6) out of the box.

[Demo @dotnetfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PORnS8) (package installed `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console` and `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json`)